# Euler Method recursive

Tags: recursion, differential-equations

I am quite new to coding in C.
I am trying to apply Eulers Method for an first order ODE in a quite simple way, both as an iterative as well as an recursive function. I can't put the recursive implementation together.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float a,b,x,y,h,b;

float fun(float x,float y)
{
    float f;
    f=x+y;
    return f;
}

float euler (float x, float y, float h, float t){
    float k;
    while(x<=b) {
        y=y+h*fun(x,y);;
        x=x+h;
        printf("%0.3f\t%0.3f\n",x,y);
        }
    };

float euler_rec (float x, float y, float h, float b){
    if (x<=b) {
        y=euler_rec(x, y, h, b)+h*fun(x,y);
        }
    else {
        printf("%0.3f\t%0.3f\n",x,y);
        }
    };

int main()
{

    printf("\nEnter x0,y0,h,xn: ");
    scanf("%f%f%f%f",&x,&y,&h,&b);

    printf("\n  x\t  y\n");

    euler(x, y, h, b);

printf ("rec\n");
    euler_rec(x, y, h, b);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using recursion depths of thousand or multiple thousands in serious applications. But for the sake of the principle, what you are trying to implement is that `euler_rec(x0,y0,h,x)` returns the solution approximation at time `x` for initial point `(x0,y0)`. Thus the recursive call should be

```c
yprev = euler_rec(x0,y0,h,x-h);
y = yprev + h*f(x-h,yprev);
```

and around that you have to construct the body of the recursion function.

---

It should amount to something like

```c
float euler_rec (float x0, float y0, float h, float x) {
    float y; 
    if(x > x0+h) {
        y = euler_rec(x0 ,y0 ,h , x-h); 
    } else {
        y = y0;
        h = x-x0;
    }
    return y + h * f(x-h, y); 
}
```

The printing has to occur outside of the recursion, or you need still another parameter that is constant over the recursion to indicate the `x` values for which some print-out should happen.

---

You can of course also use the forward recursion that is nearly not a recursion as any optimizing compiler will transform it into an iteration. The previous variant was recursion call first, computation second. If you put the computation first, recursion call second then the method reads as

```c
float euler_rec (float x, float y, float h, float b){
    if (x+1.01*h>=b) {
        h = b-x;
        return y + h * f(x,y); // insert print statement if you like
    } 
    return euler_rec(x+h, y+h*f(x,y),h,b)
}
```

Comment: The condition `x==x0` has a very low probability to be actually hit due to floating point errors, even if theoretically it all fits. You would be more robust if you were not to assume that `h` divides evenly into `x-x0`.

Comment: Here I get the start values x0, y0. `float euler_rec (float x0, float y0, float h, float x){`
    `float yprev, y;`
    `y=y0;`
    `if (x > x0) {`
        `yprev = euler_rec(x0 ,y0 ,h , x-h);`
        `y = yprev + h * f(x-h, yprev);`
        `x=x-h;
    `}`
    `else {`
       `printf("%0.3f\t%0.3f\n", x, y);`
       ` }`
   ` }`

Comment: Do you notice that you are doing nothing with the computed value `y`? What is the return value?

Comment: I thought you were suggesting a backward formula. The computed value of `y` should be summed up until the end of the recursion, and this should also be my return value.